# Accepted answer has really small font when opening full website on nexus 5

Tags: bug, design, accepted-answer

I am using the full version of the website on my Nexus 5, because only in the full version I can make reviews and flag comments.

I have noticed a quite annoying bug- the accepted answer always have a really small bug, way smaller than the other answers or the question(or even the comments):

Compared to question:

> [image]

Compared to other answer:

> [image]

Can you fix this please? It is really hard to read the accepted answer without zooming in.

EDIT: after some further investigation I have noticed that the bug is only present for chrome and not for firefox. Also it seems it is not directly related to a post being accepted. There are cases when several posts are "shrinked", but it seems the bug only affects the first few answers in a row.

EDIT2: taking another look at the screenshot there are also some comments with this annoyingly small font.

Comment: Weird. When you visit question with more than one answer and no accepted answer, are all answers appear fine? Maybe the bug is only with first answer listed, not related to  it being accepted.

Comment: Hmm actually most of the time all the answers are with small font if there is no accepted. However I have seen some exceptions where I have a single answer and it has correct font size.

Comment: Can you try with a different browser? (on the mobile device)

Comment: This might be the annoying "feature" of mobile Chrome that tries to detect important and less important text and scales it accordingly.

Comment: firefox works correctly. Apparently bug is related to chrome.

Comment: @MadScientist that's a super annoying feature indeed! Any way to disable this?

Comment: [Might be a bug after all](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84186)? (but in such case, it's off topic here)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's a similar bug on Firefox, not sure about Chrome though.

Comment: This is just the way things get rendered on Chrome for mobile. It's the same stylesheet as the full site, and the bottom line is that the full site is only supported on full, desktop browsers.